# EJB remoting + Spring DI, lacking of application context (EJB Side)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, autowired, interceptor, applicationcontext

So I have read a lot of questions, some answers helped me in some parts but at the end I haven't seen any solution to this.

Context: We have a web application created with maven/spring(JPA)/JSF deployed in wildfly 10, today we have spring beans who are processing the data coming from the different pages in the app, so when you click "some button" it calls a function in a spring bean, this calls some method via interfaces that are autowired by spring, the application context is created by web.xml and applicationContext.xml when the application is deployed, so when we just call a bean it is ready and have all the interfaces wired

The problem started when they wanted us to separate the layers, so we have to get 2 web servers, one hosting just the view (I mean the xhtmls we will call it the view server) and the other web server managing the process of data, so we are calling a remote ejb, this ejb is in the other server (we will call it the process server) so the view server calls an ejb in the process server and then this ejb has all the process that was in the view server, the problem is we need to start the application context "somewhere" (this is probably the main problem) because this ejb project doesn't have an web.xml, so far I tried using `@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)`
but as far as I understand this would work if the application context of spring is already started or something:

```
@Component
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class BitacoraBean implements BitacoraBeanRemote{
#Code with its @Autowired and methods (getters and setters)

}
```

but this gives me the following error in the log when deploying (it compiles fine, but it fails at deploying)

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0466: Failed to process business interfaces for EJB class class some.package.bean.BitacoraBean
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
```

So I tried removing the interceptor and create the applicationContext when the EJB is created (I don't like this approach since I would need to start a lot of application context, 1 for every EJB) this kind of works, I did a single java class with its main and do this exact code and I can call any SpringBean from the context (commented in the next code, the only problem is that I can't reach the datasource from the jndi because its a java main class which is not running in any server)

```
@Component
@Stateless
public class BitacoraBean implements BitacoraBeanRemote{
    public BitacoraBean(){
       /*BitacoraBean obj = (BitacoraBean) context.getBean("bitacoraBean");
        System.out.println(obj.getRfcBitacora());
        obj.setRfcBitacora("alo");
        System.out.println(obj.getRfcBitacora());*/
        
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
        
    }
```

But when I create it in the ejb which is running in the process server and call it from the view server this happens:

```
    13:47:07,733 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-8) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component BitacoraBean for method public abstract java.lang.String some.package.bean.BitacoraBeanRemote.getRfcBitacora(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
```

that's by "failing" the ejb creation, this is why it fails

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:344)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint$1.proceed(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldManagedReferenceFactory.create(WeldManagedReferenceFactory.java:51)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldConstructionStartInterceptor$1.aroundConstruct(WeldConstructionStartInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallback(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:109)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:116)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:180)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.produce(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContext.produce(WeldInjectionContext.java:46)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldConstructionStartInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldConstructionStartInterceptor.java:37)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:26)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
    at some.package.bean.bitacora.BitacoraBean.<init>(BitacoraBean.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext from [Module "deployment.EjbSite.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 105 more
```

Is it possible to start the application context like that? I tried changing the "\META-INF\applicationContext" to any possible directory of that xml.

also if it helps here is the applicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


    
    <context:component-scan base-package="some.package.bean.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    
    
    <task:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SITE_EJB" />
    </bean>


    
    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    
    <bean id="myProperties"
        class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:/conf/ce.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="true" />
        
    
  
</beans>
```

Sorry if it was too long, I wanted to describe everything we have done:
Summary: we need to create an application context on a "non-web" ejb project to be able to create a spring container so we can inject (I hope) the spring beans into our ejb, but we have failed.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to deploy just an ejb-jar. You need to give it access to your Spring Framework jars (you are failing because of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`), typically done by bundling your ejb-jar up into an EAR file which includes all the Spring dependencies. But really, you could probably convert the whole thing to pure EJBs and CDI and not use Spring at all in this layer. It would be less trouble...

Comment: in fact Iam packaging it like an ejb, I changed I added it into an EAR project and finally this kinda works, I can now initiate the context from the remote ejb and call any bean from there, probably ejbs and cdi its a better approach, but we dont really know a lot about how, we are gonna try to go this way because we also have jndis that we need to do transactions in data bases thanks for the answer was so helpfull

Comment: You get transactions for free with EJBs